# postman request to upload a file

Tags: node.js, rest, web-services, file-upload, postman

I am at this site : https://www.free-ocr.com/ which allows you to upload a file and in response returns text from that file.

When I upload a file it creates a POST request with multi-part form data with the following headers.

[image]

In return it gets the folowing response, the one in which I am interested :
[image]

However, when I try to replicate this whole thing in POSTMAN using POST method and upload a file using form-data, I do not get the same response as it was intended. Can somebody help me sort out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: postman screenshot]
[image]
you just need to select type as file in body 
then select the file .

Comment: Din't work. I already tried that before. It gives a message 'Please select a file before submitting' even though I have a file attached in my POST request.

Comment: make sure you give right "name"  attribute in key ,you might be giving wrong key that's only possible error

Comment: Not  sure by what you mean. In the key section, I use 'file' as a key and and in the value section I select the file from the file-picker.

Comment: eg <input name="file-input" type="text" > the key will be file-input in this

Comment: Hey Sanjay, thanks a lot for all the prompt responses. Your suggestion worked. Turns out, the name I was using was not matching with the one in input tag.

Comment: really happy to help